# Nginx - Password Protect Directory

Tags: shell, nginx, passwords

I want to password protect my entire site. I am running Debian Squeeze. Say I want my username to be "Jane" and my password to be "V3RySEcRe7".

In my app-nginx.conf:

`auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;`

In my shell script I have this:

`printf "Jane:$(openssl passwd -1 V3RySEcRe7)\n" >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd`

When I go to my site it is password protected, but the credentials I use don't work. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure you'd have fixed this by now, but thought I'd add this for others:

The [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) is a little cryptic on this, but does mention the "Apache variant of the MD5-based password algorithm (apr1)" should be used to generate the password hash. So using the **-apr1** flag instead of -1 will work:

```
printf "Jane:$(openssl passwd -apr1 V3RySEcRe7)\n" >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd
```